# Kmz Not load when use secure Url

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, google-earth-plugin

I have a URL where I return kmz files, the file is returned via a controller that has the following form http://dominio.com/File/Kmz/archivo.kmz
while trying to load the kmz follows

```
var link = ge.createLink('');
            var href = encodeURI("http://dominio.com/File/Kmz/archivo.kmz");
            link.setHref(href);
            var networkLink = ge.createNetworkLink(type + "-" + name);
            networkLink.set(link, true, true);
            ge.getFeatures().appendChild(networkLink);
```

When attempting to load, the following request is made,
http://dominio.com/File/Kml/files/TABLA%20of%20SIMBOLOGIA%20-%20copia_3_1_8_3_2.png which are files that are within the KMZ.

The controller code is as follows:

```
public FileResult(string id){
/*...........*/
return File(uri,"application/vnd.google-earth.kmz",string.Format("{0}-{1}","Kmz",id));
}
```

Only happens when not loading kmz contains pictures inside the polygons and markers if they are shown.

Comment: Does the kml in the kmz validate? Also, does the kmz work as expected in the full Google Earth desktop application?

Comment: yes. the kmz is valid because it can be opened in Google Earth dektop

Comment: That doesn't mean it is valid at all, I can open invalid HTML in my browser, etc. You should validate the Kml to be sure - http://kmlvalidator.com/home.htm . Also. is it perhaps the paths that are wrong? You have 'http://dominio.com/File/Kmz/...' for the kmz path, yet the images inside it have 'http://dominio.com/File/Kml/...'